# syntax to join a table twice in laravel

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to join the below 3 tables. The issue is in the part where I want to join posts.id to the shares.post_id using 'AND' operator which is not correct. What is the correct syntax to do that ?

```
$sharedPosts = DB::table('shares')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
            ->join('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id' , 'AND' , 'posts.id', '=', 'shares.post_id')
            ->where('shares.user_id', '=', $myFriends)

         ->get();
```

Comment: Not for nothing, but at what point do you say **screw this join function** and just write: `join(explode(' ', 'posts posts.user_id = users.id AND posts.id = shares.post_id'))`... those parameters would drive me insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try aliasing:

```
$sharedPosts = DB::table('shares')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
            ->join('posts as p1', 'p1.user_id', '=', 'users.id' , 'AND' , 'p1.id', '=', 'shares.post_id')
            ->join('posts as p2', 'p2.id', '=', 'shares.post_id')
            ->where('shares.user_id', '=', $myFriends)
         ->get();
```

You cannot join a table twice with no alias.

Although if you have 2 clauses in your join, I think you ought to do as in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#joins) :

```
$sharedPosts = DB::table('shares')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
    ->join('posts as p1', , function($join){
        $join->on('p1.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
             ->on('p1.id', '=', 'shares.post_id')
    })
    ->join('posts as p2', 'p2.id', '=', 'shares.post_id')
    ->where('shares.user_id', '=', $myFriends)
->get();
```

**Edit (with one posts join):**

```
$sharedPosts = DB::table('shares')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
    ->join('posts', , function($join){
        $join->on('posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
             ->on('posts.id', '=', 'shares.post_id')
    })
    ->where('shares.user_id', '=', $myFriends)
->get();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the following shouldn't be in the query :    ->join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'shares.post_id')  , which I have edited.  Can u check now ?

Comment: There is an extra comma i think in line 3 , and thanks alot

Comment: Yes, removed it :)